# Learning Bash - Configure file

Tags: sed, sh, configure

I'm decent at bash and I like to learn by looking through other's work and files i get from downloads and i came across this in a config file.

```
    # Name of the executable.
as_me=`$as_basename "$0" ||
$as_expr X/"$0" : '.*/\([^/][^/]*\)/*$' \| \
     X"$0" : 'X\(//\)$' \| \
     X"$0" : 'X\(/\)$' \| \
     .     : '\(.\)' 2>/dev/null ||
echo X/"$0" |
    sed '/^.*\/\([^/][^/]*\)\/*$/{ s//\1/; q; }
      /^X\/\(\/\/\)$/{ s//\1/; q; }
      /^X\/\(\/\).*/{ s//\1/; q; }
      s/.*/./; q'`
```

Can anyone explain how this works? I see a lot of people using the sed command with a bunch of forward and backwards slashes for substitution and whatnot, but this seems absurd.

Comment: Which config file is this from?

Comment: You should change to parentheses instead the old and outdated back tics. var=$(code)

Comment: Well seeing as  it isn't mine I can agree. If you want to suggest it to the maker just google whoever made gtk-server-2.3.1

Comment: The horrifying appearance is probably due to the need to work with as many implementations of `sh` and `sed` as possible, including some that may even predate the POSIX standard.

Comment: There are potentially 3 different commands that might be run: one named by `$as_basename`, one named by `$as_expr`, and as a last resort `sed`. `as_basename` and `as_expr` are most likely the POSIX `basename` and `expr` commands, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I would definitely suggest checking out this [link](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Sed.html)

And secondly, I'll go into some `sed` stuff:

- `sed '/`: This is the beginning of the regex search
- `^.*`: Search the beginning of line (`^`) and search for any amount (ie zero or more: `*`) of any character (`.`) Please note that when `^` is used within `[]` it means NOT in the list
- `/\([^/][^/]*\)`: Then search for a slash followed by a group of characters that do not contain a slash (`[^/][^/]*`). The `\(...\)` marks a group that can be referenced later on. I'll get to that later.
- `\/*$`: Then search for any amount of slashes and then a end of line (`$`)
- `/`: The occurrence of second, unescaped slash marks the end of regex and the beginning of what `sed` should when it finds a line that matches the regex
- `{ s//\1/; q; }`: Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what the braces are for. Normally they are used to group command but I've never it seen it used in this part of the slashes. Anyways, as mentioned `sed` allows to back-reference. `\1` is making a reference to the first (and only) grouping between the first two slashes; namely, `[^/][^/]*`. The `q` is used to quit out of `sed` when it finishes that command, but because it's in braces, I'm not exactly sure how that affects the whole command.

Anyways, that should give a decent understand of how `sed` works. From what I can tell it seems that `sed` is looking through a file path and grabbing one part of it. For example, it is passed `some/crazy/file/location.ext` it will return `crazy`
Hope that helped! Make sure you check out that link because it is a really useful tool once get the hang of it. Oh and if you ever use `sed` please please please use `:` or `_` or even `|` as your delimiter!! This prevents the disgusting picket-fence look of the `sed` see above. It could have been written as

```
sed ':^.*/\([^/][^/]*\)/*$:{ s::\1:; q; }
      :^X/\(//\)$:{ s::\1:; q; }
      :^X/\(/\).*:{ s::\1:; q; }
      s:.*:.:; q'
```

which I concede is not easy to understand but it is easier to read.